# Get fsmonitor to run on nitros.io

Tags: nitrousio

My build scripts use fsmonitor (npm install -g fsmonitor) to auto run scripts when files change.

I cannot get fsmonitor to work. You can verify this by running `fsmonitor` and then changing/saving a file. Nothing happens, but if you `touch` a file, you'll see output.

Is this an issue with how the Nitrous.io IDE saves files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE SEPT 2nd 2013**

We recently updated the filesystem on any new boxes, so inotify is now supported.  Your build scripts using fsmonitor should work correctly on any new boxes you create.

We'll be adding your box's version number in the boxes index page.  Boxes in Version2 and later will be using the new filesystem and will support inotify.